# What is the mathematical symbol for the sum of numbers

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, summation

For example, when $n=5$, what is the symbol for $5+4+3+2+1$?

Comment: $\sum$ is the symbol you are looking for (then you have to precise where to start and where to end the sum)

Comment: For a sum we usually employ this symbol: $∑$. In your example,we have: $∑_{n=1}^{5}n=1+2+3+4+5$

Comment: I can't believe you haven't found [this](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=sum&oq=sum+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i65j69i59j69i60.1192j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=sum+symbol) on google.

Comment: If you google "mathematical symbol for the sum of numbers", the first result is this question. The second result is the Wikipedia article on "Summation".

Comment: The symbol is $15$ :)

Answer (score 5):

Usually we use the symbol $$\sum$$
(capital sigma).

You can write $$1+2+3+4+5 = \sum_{k=1}^5 k$$

another example is

$$1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2 = \sum_{k=1}^5k^2$$

Note that if you want to write $5+4+3+2+1$ instead of $1+2+3+4+5$, you can also write

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 (6-k) =(6-1)+(6-2)+(6-3)+(6-4)+(6-5)= 5+4+3+2+1$$
See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

That is the fifth triangular number, which is [sometimes written as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)
$$T_5$$

The triangular numbers have their own symbol since they have been studied since the ancient Greeks. The Pythagoreans revered the [Tetractys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetractys) which is $T_4$. Triangular numbers have applications to other areas of number theory, such as perfect numbers and binomial coefficients. They are also practically the simplest example of an arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a theorem than a definition, but
$$1+2+\cdots+n=\binom{n+1}2=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no symbol just for this (like the factorial for multiplication) because the result of this operation can be written in closed-form so easily: $$\sum _{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: The factorial can also be easily written in closed form, you know...

Comment: Also, you just wrote the "symbol" which is $\sum_{k=1}^n k$

Comment: @HasanSaad How can be factorial written in a closed form?

Comment: @Antoine $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$. Maybe you might object that I considered the Gamma function a closed form, but noting that it has a known form as an integral and is not a specification of a function with certain properties, it is thus a closed form.

Comment: @Antoine Via the gamma function, but that is not as accessible as the expression for the sum I have given.

Comment: I am not saying you made a mistake since you did not explicitly state that the factorial doesn't have a closed form, but I'm just saying it does.

Comment: @HasanSaad I object, of course, known integral form is not a valid argument for me (and many others, since it is commonly said that $\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$ has no closed form).

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am wrong then.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a symbol just for this, since the triangular numbers have been revered (by the Pythagoreans) and studied (by many) for many years. See my answer or the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Answer (score 1):

Your expression would  be $$\sum_{i=1}^5 i$$

And for any $n$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n i$$

Answer (score 1):

For $$1+2+3+4+.....\infty = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}{k}$$

Here for some finite value you can write in place of infinity some finite value $k$.

Now you might ask how will I represent a product like $a_1a_2a_3.....a_n$. It is represented as:

$$\prod^{n}_{k=1} {a_k}$$

Comment: It's better to just write $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \dots$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this question refers to finding a summation equivalent of the factorial symbol (!), and not the summation symbol $\sum$. For one, this is what I was looking for when I reached this page. I am not sure there is a symbol for that though.